# Method or Data Member Not Found error when building a recordset

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I've been out of Access for a bit, and having some trouble with a somewhat simple concept.  I want to loop through the records of a subform and adjust inventory numbers after a sale.  The looping through the subform tested fine, but when I tried to add the bit about adjusting inventory I received a Method or Data Member Not Found error.  For S&G's, I pasted the SQL into an empty query and it returned the data just fine.  I must not be DIM-ing something right?  The error comes when it attempts to set rec2 = db.OpenRecordset.  The error falls specifically on rec2.StockQuantity, but as I've said the field exists when I just paste the rec2 code into an empty query.

Here's the full code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub bnUpdate_Click()
Dim db As Database
Dim rec As Recordset
Dim rec2 As Recordset
Dim MsgBx1 As String
Dim X As String
Dim Y As String

Me.Refresh
Me.Parent.Refresh
Me.Parent!TotalSale.Value = Me.txtPriceSum.Value
MsgBx1 = MsgBox("Do you want to save the record?", vbYesNo, "Save Sale")
If MsgBx1 = vbYes Then

Set rec = Me.Form.Recordset
Do While rec.EOF = False
X = Me.UPC

Set rec2 = db.OpenRecordset("Select SKU, StockQuantity from tblProduct where SKU = '" & X & "'")
rec2.Edit
Y = rec2.StockQuantity
rec2.StockQuantity = Y - 1
rec2.Update

Set rec2 = Nothing

'MsgBox X
rec.MoveNext
Loop

Else
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Y = rec2!StockQuantity`

Comment: Bang,  Dot.  BANG!  That stuff drove me nuts from Day 1.  Thanks, braX.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with a lot of modifications:

```vb
Private Sub bnUpdate_Click()

    Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rec2 As DAO.Recordset

    Dim MsgBx1 As Long
    Dim X As String
    Dim Y As Long

    Me.Refresh
    Me.Parent.Refresh
    Me.Parent!TotalSale.Value = Me!txtPriceSum.Value
    MsgBx1 = MsgBox("Do you want to save the record?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Save Sale")
    If MsgBx1 = vbYes Then
        
        Set rec = Me.RecordsetClone
        rec.MoveFirst
        Do While rec.EOF = False
            X = rec!UPC.Value
            Set rec2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select SKU, StockQuantity from tblProduct where SKU = '" & X & "'")
            Y = rec2!StockQuantity.Value
            rec2.Edit
                rec2!StockQuantity.Value = Y - 1
            rec2.Update
            rec2.Close
            rec.MoveNext
        Loop
        rec.Close

    End If

End Sub
```